# Magento 2 - Cannot create Backup

Tags: magento2, backup

I'm trying to install a magento2 extension and while running the installation process magento tells me that I do not have enough disk space available.

Running `df -h` tells me, that I have 275 GB of free space which should be quite enough for a magento backup.

I verified that *./var/* and *./var/backups/* belongs to the *www-data* group and that the group has the permissions to write in this directory.

I'm unable to skip this step an cannot figure out what I need to change in order to get to the next step.

[image: Magento2 Create Backup error]

Comment: Review this: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/comp-mgr/trouble/cman/tshoot_backup.html

Comment: I have checked this page before but the mentioned articles explain what to do if *df -h* says that your disk space is full **or** if your disk space is actually full. Other processes and tasks can write on the disk (even large files) so it seems as if it is not a general disk problem.